# when is a queue full?

Tags: data-structures, queue

I have seen many ways to check when a queue is full, but I don`t understand any, so in simple words when is a queue full?

(If there is a code please make it in C++ or pseudocode)

I have this code to check if the queue is full:-

```
myFront != (myBack+1) % max
```

(e.g. why isn`t it simply " myBack == max ")

Comment: Are we talking about multi threaded (parallelized) code?

Comment: Your question is based on a particular implementation of a queue (perhaps one implemented using a fixed-size array in circular fashion, judging by the single line of code you show). There are many valid ways to implement a queue; without knowing the specifics of the implementation you're asking about, it's pretty hard to answer a question about a single isolated line of code.

Comment: I didn't there are more than one implementation, but I think yes, it`s a circular queue...so, how do we check if a circular queue is full (in simple words)?

Comment: There's many ways to implment a queue or a circular queue. Where did you get `myFront != (myBack+1) % max` from - and are you sure it is correct ?

Comment: @nos my teacher wrote it on board today... I am not sure it`s correct!

Answer (score 2):

A queue is full when you have no more space to enqueue/insert new items whether do to storage constraints, or programmatic constraints. (assuming its bounded)

Check [here(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29#Example_C.23_Class) and it shows a C# example with a "size" limit.

Code snippet(from link above):

```
#region Constructor
public Queue(int Size)
 {
     this._Size = Size;
 }

 //Enqueue
if (this.IsFull())
{
    throw new Exception("Queue is full !");
}
... do enqueue

// check full
public virtual bool IsFull()
{
   return (this._Count == this._Size);
}
```

Comment: for example this: myFront != (myBack+1) % max ... I don`t get it

Comment: Its a circular way of seeing if you have reached the size.. instead of storing a count, you just check to see if the next item/current item completes the circle (aka remainder equal to the first element)

Comment: @delive there is a link there for a reason.  I didn't want to take all the code from wikipedia.  Take a look at the link it has the full source.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) cited by Helper Method gives a very good explanation of this (including diagrams) that I won't try to repeat here.

The "myFront != (myBack+1) % max" test implies that the code is using the "Always Keep One Slot Open" strategy to detect a full queue; there's sample code in the wikipedia article that uses the exact same test for "buffer full" (they write it as: `(end + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE != start`).

In case it's not clear, the purpose of the "(myBack+1) % max" is to add 1 to myBack, and if the result == max, instead set the result to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be about a circular queue implemented with an array.  In this case, `myFront`, `myBack` and `myBack+1` must all be in the range `[0,max)`. Most of the time you could check for a full queue by checking `myFront != (myBack+1)`. The one additional case where this simple check would fail to be true is where `myBack==max-1` and `myFront==0`. Adding in the modulus `%` makes the code simpler by wrapping the two cases into one check becuause `(max-1)+1 % max == 0`.